# jquery next() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like so:

```
var parent = $("#delete-button").closest('div');
var head = parent.prev('h3');
var linktext = head.next('a');
```

the code up to:

```
var parent = $("#delete-button").closest('div');
var head = parent.prev('h3');
```

works fine, I'm able to use both parent and head vars, however:

```
var linktext = head.next('a');
```

does not seems to be working fine, because:

```
alert(linktext.html());
```

returns `null`

---

HTML (no div and #delete-button, sorry):

```
<h3 class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all" role="tab" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>
    <a href="#" tabindex="-1">first</a>
</h3>
```

Comment: Assuming that everything works up until `linktext`, I think you might want to use `head.find('a');` But this depends *entirely* upon your HTML, at least *some* of which doesn't appear to be present in your question.

Comment: `.next()` locates a sibling node. If you want the `<a>` inside `<h3>`, use `.find()`.

Comment: this is happening because parent is not a collection, it's a single element - .next gets the next sibling in a collection, not the next sibling in the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because next searches for siblings (and only IMMEDIATE siblings, if the selector is not matched, it returns an empty set), while you're searching for a child. Try

```
head.find('a')
```

instead.